# Foreach loop working, but outputting "invalid argument"?

Tags: php, arrays

I hope to give enough information here, but I am confused as to why the `foreach` loop works, it gets each data and outputs it in an `li` but I am getting an invalid argument error?

Here is the result of the `var_dump`

```
array(1) { ["questions"]=> 
    array(2) { ["title"]=> string(5) "Keanu" [1]=> 
        array(1) { ["questionlist"]=> array(2) { [0]=> 
            array(1) { 
                ["a-question"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { 
                ["a-question"]=> string(5) "civil" } } } } }
```

Here is my `foreach` statement

```
foreach($questions['questions'] as $key => $value){    
            foreach($value['questionlist'] as $key => $subquestion){ //line 119

                 echo '<li>'.$subquestion['a-question'].'</li>';

            }
}
```

`$questions` is a variable used to get the data from the database like this.

```
$questions = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" , ARRAY_A);
```

The data comes from ajax, I modify the ajax `$_POST` like this before sending to the database.

```
    // Add modifications
    $questions['questions'] = $_POST['questions']['data'];

    // DB data
    $name = $wpdb->escape($questions['questions']['title']);
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($questions));
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting the invalid argument, I suspect its because the array may not be formatted properly, if you need any more information let me know.

**A Solution:** *Thanks to @didierc*

I used his code and modified it a bit to display my data in a loop, basically all I did was add another `foreach`.

```
 foreach($questions['questions'] as $key => $value){   
   if(is_array($value) && isset($value[ 'questionlist'])){
       foreach($value as $key => $subquestion){ //line 119
           foreach ($subquestion as $key => $value){

               // This loops all the ['a-question'] data
               echo '<li>''.$value['a-question'].''</li>';

           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Which one is line 119?

Comment: Good question its `foreach($value['questionlist'] as $key => $subquestion)` the second foreach in the nest.

Comment: I `var_dump ($subquestion);` and got `array(1) { ["a-question"]=> string(1) "1" }

array(1) { ["a-question"]=> string(5) "civil" } ` it returnd no errors, but perhaps theres something up with `$value['questionlist'] `

Comment: The error usually happens when the given argument is *not* an array. `print_r($value['questionlist']);` - what does it output? Maybe edit the question and add the formatted output

Comment: That out puts `Array ( [0] => Array ( [a-question] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [a-question] => civil ) ) ` so does that mean it is not 1 but its 2 arrays? I need to reformat that dont I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($questions['questions'] as $key => $value) {   
        if (is_array($value) && isset($value[ 'questionlist']))  {
            foreach ($value['questionlist'] as $subnum => $subquestion) {
                foreach ($subquestion as $qtitle => $qanswer) {
```

With variable names hopefully explicit enough. That should get you started.

NB: The data is probably easier to understand when formatted as below:

```
array(1) {
 ["questions"]=> array(2) { 
    ["title"] => string(5) "Keanu"
    [1]      =>  array(1) { 
        ["questionlist"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=>   array(1) { 
                ["a-question"]=> string(1) "1" 
            }
            [1]=> array(1) { 
                ["a-question"]=> string(5) "civil"
            }
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ahhh, nice catch on my answer. Hard to read var_dumps with out <pre> tags lol

Comment: Thanks so much I was waiting for a solid answer, let me play with it, ill update the OP. Could you explain the answer if you have time, I am really trying to learn to be better working with arrays.

Comment: Ok I got it working I added a little mod to suit my code, ill post it in the OP. If you dont mind though could you answer a question? Is the original way I had it giving the error because of the way the array was formatted? If I reformat the array could I use the foreach format I had originally? Also any good resources on reading arrays and logically matching the keys and values? Ill dig as much as I can to find good resources, but a few shares would be stellar!

Comment: Sorry, I left a stale answer. Perhaps you could try playing with that one instead?

Comment: Often time a problem becomes much easier to understand when seen under the right angle. I find that formatting the var dump like I did makes the array structure more apparent, but that's my opinion, indeed YMMV.

Comment: Yeah I like how you formatted the var_dump, basically the nested array like above is like a tree or a better analogy would be a Matryoshka doll http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll right? Lol and calling the peice of data you want in a foreach is like taking it apart? Is this a good analogy? Because this is how I look at arrays, would you say that it is an intuitive or counter intuitive way of looking at a nested array? `['questions']` being the big doll and `["a-question"]` being the little dolls inside. You don't have to answer this is really for fun..

Comment: I suppose your analogy works. Php arrays are nesting data structures.